# Moving a Drupal site from plain HTTP to HTTPS - Issues?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm planning to move a site from plain HTTP to HTTPS. Should I make any adjustments to the settings or my modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. There are few thing you need to keep in mind

1. Make sure they are no absolute URLs in your node text etc. because in that case the path would remain http://yoursitename.com/some/path instead of https://yoursitename/some/path . with relative URLs the paths should get changed automatically to the correct URL with https
2. Make sure that your server does not concurrently continue to serve pages over http for your website if you don't want that to happen. You will have to disable that directory in your apache configuration
3. You might want to continue serving images for instance as http instead https (or maybe you want that to be https also). Also you might want to have some redirects happening to users accessing the site using the http protocol. If you're using secure pages module then you can configure some of these issues (and more!) http://drupal.org/project/securepages